# how to login to RealVNC automatically(without giving user/password every time)

Tags: vnc, realvnc, vnc-viewer

any idea how to login to RealVNC automatically(without giving user/password every time).

like how we can login to putty:

```
putty.ext username@11.222.43.64 -pw password
```

Answer (score 2):

Two solutions:

1) If you feel that there is no security concern (both pcs on a well-protected LAN), then you can simply disable password on the server, just leave the field empty.

2) If instead you wish to leave some security in place, you can save session information from the F8 menu or the menu in the top bar. Make sure that you include your password, and that the file saved has extension `.vnc`. Next time, you may just click on this saved file, and your session will be restarted without asking for a password.

Answer (score 2):

Do not know how to do this when using Windows, but when you use Unix-like OS-es, it is possible to create vnc password file, execute `% vncpasswd ~/.vncpassword`, enter password, that you use to connect to vnc server, after it is possible to connect "automatically" using

`% vncviewer -passwd ~/.vncpassword user@X.X.X.X:X`

without password request.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows (not verified on other platforms):

- Add a new connection via the gui in the standard manner
- Goto File...Export Connections

You will be given a choice regarding exporting with or without the passwords.  If exporting with passwords, they will appear in CLEAR TEXT within the exports.  If you do not include the passwords, you will be prompted each time you employ one.

Ideally, there should be the option to tap the same "password store" that is used within the application, but I did not find a method for this.  Perhaps someone can share this detail?

Btw, those exports are .vnc files.  Double-clicking on one will instantly start the connection.  You don't have to explicitly pass the config path via the command line or a shortcut etc.  You can also drag and drop them onto the task bar (saving and "stacking them" them there) for fast access.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the command with 'Process Hacker 2' and tried to resolve the automatic connection.
I've written this on my blog, so if you're interested, I recommend you translate it and follow it.
To explain briefly, I tried to connect automatically using the 'recent item' in Windows, and after checking the command with 'Process Hacker 2' about it, I checked if it was connected automatically to CMD and found that it worked well.

My blog : https://all-share-source-code.tistory.com/63

The command I used is as follows.

```
...(Path\according\to\the\user)...\vncviewer.exe -UseAddressBook 192.168.0.22
```

This command may differ for each user.

Answer (score -1):

create shortcut link:

"C:\Program Files\uvnc bvba\UltraVNC\vncviewer.exe" -connect 192.1.121.50 -password myawesomepass

Comment: Question is for RealVNC, not UltraVNC

Answer (score -1):

In RealVNC software. Use `File / Export Connections` will export an excutable `.vnc` file with your saved connections. (you have the option to store password within)

the exported file will look something like this:

```
ConnMethod=tcp
ConnTime=2020-12-26T13:00:44.803Z 
FriendlyName=192.168.1.200:5900
FullScreen=0 
Host=192.168.1.200:5900
Password=d987f88wud72db1bwidk8ey7aa21c915
RelativePtr=0 
Scaling=100%
Uuid=848af6d6-adb3-4588-ac30-afe48c2ce473
```